# Select Statement AVG function Subquery 1242 Error

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a subquery in my select statement to use an average function. However, I am getting a 1242 error when running the subquery with the group by clause, which I know is causing the error. However, when I remove the group by clause and add it in later in the function the global average is not averaging by product line. I'm not sure how to get my average to follow the group by function in the code.

```
Select 
    pl.productline, 
    year(orderdate), 
    sum(quantityordered * priceeach) 'Revenue', 
    avg(quantityordered * priceeach) as 'max rev', 
    min(quantityordered * priceeach) as 'min rev', 
    std(quantityordered * priceeach) as 'std of rev', 
    count(distinct o.ordernumber) 'Annual # of Orders',
    (select avg(quantityordered * priceeach) as 'glob rev'
     from productlines pl
     left join products p on pl.productline = p.productline
     left join orderdetails od on p.productcode = od.productcode
     group by pl.productline) 'avg global rev'
from 
    productlines pl
inner join 
    products p on pl.productline = p.productline
inner join 
    orderdetails od on p.productcode = od.productcode
inner join 
    orders o on od.ordernumber = o.ordernumber
inner join 
    customers c on o.customernumber = c.customernumber
where 
    country = 'USA'
group by 
    pl.productline, year(orderdate)
order by 
    productline;
```

[image]

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using (I can't be Postgres as your query is invalid standard SQL and would be rejected by Postgres)

Comment: What is the actual error message? No (sane) developer is going to know what a "1242 error" is off the top of their head, especially without knowing which DBMS you're using.

Comment: In general ANSI/ISO SQL, single quotes are for string literals, and double quotes for identifiers, e.g.  `"glob rev"`.

Comment: The 'avg global rev' subquery will most probably return more than 1 row, which will give you an error.